# Component Diagram for an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uml, component-diagram

I need to draw a component diagram for an Eclipse plugin, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I found [this diagram](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=eclipse%20architecture%20plugin&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&biw=1138&bih=524&tbm=isch&tbnid=gMaaq6b9JS-YvM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecjdt/&docid=uDbzNUv8Oeo4FM&w=489&h=322&ei=eJRCTvPzCoL10gGS1qHxCQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=513&vpy=221&dur=366&hovh=182&hovw=277&tx=146&ty=102&page=1&tbnh=99&tbnw=151&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:9,s:0). I think I could draw something similar using the UML 2 notation for my plugin, replacing "Your tool" with  the name of my plugin and "Their tool" with the name(s) of the plugin(s)  my plugin uses.

What do you think? Thank you very much!

PD: Yes, I have read about component diagrams, but I'm really lost here.

Edit: for example: I'm developing a plugin using Xtext and Xpand and MySQL, so I guess my components would be: MyPlugin, Xtext, Xpand, MySQL and Eclipse itself. Is it correct?

Now, what would be a Xtext or Eclipse interface to connect to other components?

Comment: The figure you referenced is rather generic. I'd expect your component diagram to show the relation to the Dependencies and used Extensions of your plugin. Can you clarify what the diagram you have to provide will be used for?

Comment: It's a requirement from my client, even though he does not know much about UML. He just think it is safe to have some documentation. Maybe too much detail will only confuse him.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what makes you uncertain? If you have Eclipse Plugin, know about its dependencies (ports and interfaces) and composition (parts and artifacts), and know how to depict them using UML, just try doing that. If you have a problem expressing something, let us know:)

Comment: If the diagram shouldn't serve your client directly and he asks for documentation, most probably he wants to ensure the plugin could be easily mantained in the future. For a future developer of the eclipse plugin provided metadata should suffice (e.g. MANIFEST.MF, plugin.xml and build.xml). Try explaining that to your client. If you cannot, use information from that sources to draw the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not an UML expert therefore you could try UMLet. This is very very basic as well as simple and would create component diagrams in few minutes.
For more advance needs I would recommend to use a tool having not only a graphical editor but also an UML model such as Topcased or Papyrus.
For very advanced needs I would recommend RSA IBM. Omondo is recommended if you have the need for the class diagram and java code generation.